# Vue 3 with typescript eventBus auto logout

Tags: typescript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3

I currently have a fairly robust Vue 2 web application. I am starting to tinker with Vue 3 as we look towards implementing that in future years, and I had a question for those of you with more Vue 3 experience. I am trying to figure out how to replicate the behavior of EventBus. I used this to watch for a lost session and auto logout users and was implemented as such:

event-bus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

which I could use in my component:

````
import { EventBus } from '@/event-bus'

  export default {
    name: 'Appheader',
    data() {
      return {
        whois: this.$store.getters.getGuidWhoIs,
        role: this.$store.getters.getRole,
        returnurl: this.$store.getters.getReturnURL,
        showIdleModal: false,
        showLostSession: false,
        idleTime: 0,
        url: process.env.VUE_APP,
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        // every 60 seconds - call function timerIncrement
        setInterval(this.timerIncrement, 5000)
        // created listeners for user inputs that call function for resetting idle timer.
        window.onmousemove = this.resetTimer
        window.onmousedown = this.resetTimer // catches touchscreen presses as well
        window.ontouchstart = this.resetTimer // catches touchscreen swipes as well
        window.onclick = this.resetTimer // catches touchpad clicks as well
        window.onkeydown = this.resetTimer
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.resetTimer, true) // scrolling on any device
      })
      EventBus.$on('LostSession', this.lostSession)```


I have tried using a few different event-emitter libraries that support typescript (tiny-typed-emitter, emittery) but I feel like there is something silly that I am missing in how to implement this.

Unlike typical event-emitters, I am trying to watch for system events like idle time etc. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?
````

Comment: It's unclear what's your concern and why this isn't a dupe of the questions where tiny-emitter, etc are suggested as a replacement. Most times you won't need global emitter because global store serves a similar purpose

Comment: @EstusFlask can the global store work in this situation where I need to continually check for user activity across all components and display warnings, log them out etc? In my current setup, my EventBus sits in a header component that is always present

Comment: Yes. You can set up watchers on reactive data. Instead of EventBus.$on there would be watch(() => globalStore.lostSession, ...) In some cases this may not be convenient but if this is some boolean flag then that's it.